# Java - Fluentlenium how to run TestNG with threading for 1 method

Tags: java, selenium

I have a basic test using TestNG. When I run the test using invocationcount = 2, threadpoolsize = 2 (just for testing), I can see in intellij that the tests is running currently but only one browser open.

Heres' my code:

```html
public class GoogleTesting extends FluentTestNg {

    // Defines the Driver
    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    @Override
    public WebDriver newWebDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @Test(invocationCount = 2, threadPoolSize = 2)
        public void GoogleTest(){

        goTo("http://google.com");
        System.out.println(getCookies());
        }
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Because you are opening only one browser window... Move the driver initialization inside the test method and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have one webdriver instance and calling in two threads. You can try with thread local WebDriver as given below.

```
public class GoogleTesting extends FluentTestNg { 

// Defines the Driver
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> WebDriverTL = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

public void setWebdriver(Webdriver driver){
 WebDriverTL.set(driver);
}

@Override 
public WebDriver newWebDriver() { 
 return WebDriverTL.get ();
} 

@beforeMethod
public void launch browser(){
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     setWebdriver(driver);
}

@Test(invocationCount = 2, threadPoolSize = 2) 
public void GoogleTest(){
        goTo("http://google.com");                         
        System.out.println(getCookies());
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Its launching two browsers concurrently now. The only now is to troubleshoot why its erroring after it launches.